# Как убрать лишние логи из консоли Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

В последнее время появились лишние логи в консоли браузера Chrome, уже все перепробовал, а убрать их не получается (они отображаются с шестеренкой в начале названия)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

devTools Edge
[image: devTools Edge]

Comment: Что значит лишние? При доступе к сайту, очевидно прописаны скрипты, которые нужны странице для корректной работы. Они и грузятся во вкладке сеть. Не хотите видеть какие-то из них, настройте фильтр или укажите, что хотите видеть, например, только JS, ну и так далее.

Comment: К примеру в edge и fireFox консоль выгдят как на втором скриншоте, без применения каких-либо фильтров

Comment: Допускаю, что разные браузеры в инструментах разработчика могут вести себя по-разному. К тому же, на верхнем скрине у вас после названий файлов имеются числа. Сдаётся мне, что это версии скриптов при кэшировании. Как поменяется вывод в хроме, если вы отключите вывод кэша?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину. Во вкладке "Приложение" был зарегистрирован service worker, который и выводил данные логи в консоль сети.